# In Visual Studio 2022, how can I change the null check template?

Tags: c#, coding-style, visual-studio-2022, code-snippets, null-check

I frequently apply null checks to my parameters when developing in C# (like any good developer should!).

Because I can be lazy, I'd prefer to let Visual Studio add these for me, which it can.

However, when it adds the null checks, it consumes 4 lines of code per check.  For example:

```
if (a is null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
}
```

That's ridiculous!

In an ideal world, it would just add a `!` to the parameter name, some silly people canceled that feature, so I go for the second best option:

```
    _ = a ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
```

Is there a way I can make Visual Studio 2022 work with me on this?

Comment: try modifying the settings for code style and formatting.under Tools > Options > Text Editor > c# > Code Style.
if you scrolled down there is a 'null' checking section

Comment: @Nour, do I need to be explicit that I am using Visual Studio 2022 Pro?  I can't find any null checking section in formatting.  I see General, Indentation, New Lines, Spacing, and Wrapping.  Searching for "null" yields "No results found".

Comment: I think Nour means this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp8Lj.png

Comment: Unfortunately that setting has no effect! (I just tried it). Most annoying. Somewhat related: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68326

Comment: @MatthewWatson, that works (for me), but only when the value will be assigned, not when it will be discarded (which is the context I'm presently concerned with).

Comment: @Nour, Thanks for the clarification.  I actually already had that configured, but it isn't working when I want to discard instead of assign the value.